# Centralized repository github

Tags: git, github, collaboration

My colleagues and I started not so long ago to collaborate on github.
At the moment, we have one shared common repository in which we have sub-repositories. Each of us is commonly working on these sub-repositories but we're rarely working simultaneously on the same sub-repository (they're all different scripts, different purposes), still we need to be able to access latest developments of others in their sub-repositories.
My issue is that when i tried to create a branch on one of 'my' sub-repositories, the branch got created on the whole global repository, not just the sub-repository i attended to, which i find very confusing.

So i'm guessing there is something not quite right in our collaborative approach.

My thinking is that instead of having one common repository, we should each have our own repositories and share them with each other. Or maybe it is actually possible to do a branch on a sub-repository?

Happy to hear some thoughts on this!

Comment: It's really hard to suggest on your exact needs and branching strategy. But I'd suggest using this : https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/

Comment: There's a plethora of github videos so you can formulate what best will work for you

Answer (score 0):

While some version control systems encourage multiple projects per repository, Git works best with one project per repository. Github also works best with one project per repository.

Make one repository per project. You can [give each other collaborator access to your repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-access-to-your-personal-repositories). Better is to [make an organization](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/collaborating-with-groups-in-organizations) for all your collective repositories and manage permissions via the organization.

Comment: Thank youfor sharing these resources, that's very useful! :)